# MemoryError occures in python when using the kronecker product

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I defined a function like that:

```
def calc(x,y,B):
    ar = np.array([x,y])
    a = (ar[1] - B) / ar[0]
    la = len(a)
    z = np.kron(a, ar[0]).reshape((la,la)) - ar[1] + B
    s = np.sqrt(a**2 + B).reshape((la,1))
    sums = np.sum(np.abs(z/s), axis=1)

    return a[np.argmin(sums)]
```

I have a dataframe which length is 660000 like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[range(1,660001)],'y':[range(660000,0,-1)]
```

And I use the function to calculate:

```
calc(df.x, df.y,1)
```

but it went wrong：`MemoryError`. How to deal with it?

Comment: `z.shape` will be (660000, 660000).  Try `np.zeros(...)` with that, and see if that produces a memory error!

Comment: I think your best bet is to try to reformulate that mathematically so you can do the summations first.  I think the resulting equation is sepearable that way.